# R: duplicates elimination in a matrix, keeping track of multiplicities

Tags: r, matrix

I have a basic problem with R.
I have produced the matrix

```
M
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "1" 
[2,] "b"  "2" 
[3,] "a"  "3" 
[4,] "c"  "1"
```

I would like to obtain the 3X2 matrix

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "1"  "3" 
[2,] "b"  "2"  NA  
[3,] "c"  "1"  NA
```

obtained by eliminating duplicates in `M[,1]` and writing in `N[i,2], N[i,3]` the values in `M[,2]` corresponding to the same element in `M[,1]`, for all i's. The `"NA"`'s in `N[,3]` correspond to the singletons in `M[,1]`.

I know how to eliminate duplicates from a vector in R: my problem is to keep track of the elements in `M[,2]` and write them in the resulting matrix `N`. I tried with `for` cycles but they do not work so well in my "real world" case, where the matrices are much bigger.

Any suggestions?

I thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dcast` in the reshape2 package after turning your matrix to a data.frame. To reverse the process you can use `melt`.

```
df = data.frame(c("a","b","a","c"),c(1:3,1))
colnames(df) = c("factor","obs")
require(reshape2)
df2=dcast(df, factor ~ obs)
```

now `df2` is:

```
 factor  1  2  3
1      a  1 NA  3
2      b NA  2 NA
3      c  1 NA NA
```

To me it makes more sense to keep it like this. But if you need it in your format:

```
res = t(apply(df2,1,function(x) {  newLine = as.vector(x[which(!is.na(x))],mode="any"); newLine=c(newLine,rep(NA, ncol(df2)-length(newLine) )) }))
res = res[,-ncol(res)]                           

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  " 1" " 3"
[2,] "b"  " 2" NA  
[3,] "c"  " 1" NA
```

Comment: I did not know that function: I thank you very much. It works fine on my matrices!